# Redmine - How to change the project and issues URLs?

Tags: url, project, redmine

I am used to JIRA url style: domain.com/browse/projectIdentifier-issueNumber
eg. domain.com/browse/ACN-456

**Can I configure Redmine to use the same url mapping like JIRA?** Now my configuration offers something like this:

for projects: domain.com/projects/projectIdentifier
for issues: domain.com/issues/issueNumber

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with Rails or Rails-style frameworks, you could edit `config/routes.rb` and change the routing.  But you'd have to fix quite a lot of URLs and deal with the REST-style ones somehow.

This is probably not worth the effort, honestly.  I assume Redmine omits the project from issue URLs because issues can move between projects, which would break links for no good reason.

Comment: I imagined that the cross-project linking feature had something to do with the url mapping. Even when I'm not interested in that feature, I think it now makes sense to me. Thanks for your quick response.